# Problem moving a MySQL data directory to a new drive

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance and am trying to move the mysql data directory from the default drive to another EBS volume. I moved the mysql directory in `/var/lib/mysql` to the new destination and then modified the `my.cnf` file to point the data directory to the new location. I then tried to restart mysql I get the following message.

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I am running the default distribution of linux that comes with a new EC2 instance. Below are details to the `my.cnf` file and `mysqld.log`. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
datadir=/root/appfinder/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Set permissions for folder

```
chmod -R 777 /root/appfinder/mysql
```

mysqld.log

```
110616 18:37:53 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /root/appfinder/mysql
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'plugin' is read only
110616 18:37:53 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 0 37356   
110616 18:37:53  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...  
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 0 44233
110616 18:37:53  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66$
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
110616 18:37:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
5110616 18:37:53 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'host' is read only
110616 18:37:53 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remount my EBS volumes to `/myFolder` rather than `/root/myFolder`. This seems to have corrected the permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

/root/appfinder/mysql director must be owner mysql. For this, chown mysql:mysql 
/root/appfinder/mysql and chown -R mysql:mysql /root/appfinder/mysql/.

All data files for mysql must be owner mysql.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion. I used `chown -R mysql:mysql /root/appfinder/mysql/`, which should recursively apply to any items in the directory, but it appears to not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

Here are my steps that did work on Ubuntu 12.04 Lts: 
Want to move datafiles from /var/lib/mysql to /newdir_path/newdir

1. sudo mysql stop
2. sudo rsync -av /var/lib/mysql /newdir_path/newdir
3. sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf, change datadir to /newdir_path/newdir
4. sudo gedit /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld, change:

     instead of:
     - /var/lib/mysql/ r,
     - /var/lib/mysql/** /rwk
  enter:
  - /newdir_path/newdir/ r,
  - /newdir_path/newdir/** rwk,
5. sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
6. (!!!) sudo chown mysql:mysql **/newdir_path**
7. sudo start mysql

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Thanks for sharing what worked. Please know that gedit may not be installed in all the servers.