# Failed to start mysql after moving to new partition

Tags: mysql

I used to use mysql data in /var/lib/mysql, now I have created new partition and created tank on it to use with zfs.

After that I follow this steps to move my existing mysql data to new dir: https://serverfault.com/a/539729/184573

Everything worked ok so I have imported new big db (100 GB) and now is not working anymore.

I'm getting this error
[image]

in "/var/log/mysql/error.log"

Detailed explanation:

1. I'm on /tank/mysql, using zfs and everything is working ok
2. imported new db, mysql was working ok
3. stopped mysql service and executed zfs
4. snapshot tank/mysql@imported now I cannot start mysql because of
   upper error
5. tried to chown mysql:mysql /tank/mysql -R , still same error

I have google that problem and none of solutions helped me. Permissions, settings,... everything seems to be ok.

OS: Ubuntu server 14.04.

Server: IBM X3200 m3

What could be a problem?

Thank you

Comment: Looks surely like a file permission related issue. Can u pls post ls -l output from inside the mysql datadir?

Comment: @ksm - permissions are same as in /var/lib/mysql. When I switch back to /var/lib/mysql it is working ok

Comment: @ksm - if you need any more info please let me know

Comment: How did u copy the files to the new dir? What user were u logged in as? Did u run 'chown -R mysql:mysql *" to the mysql directory after copy completed?

Comment: @ksm - yes I did. With old data was working so I have imported new db when I was already using /tank/mysql and zfs

Comment: @ksm - added "Detailed explanation" in my question

Comment: Does the user mysql have access to /tank itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42215/discussion-between-croios-and-ksm).

Comment: @ksm - working now. so no matter chown mysql:mysql /tank/mysql I had to chown mysql:mysql /tank
Why? how to fix that because my elastic user needs access to /tank/elastic

Comment: Right. So it was a permissions issue. U need to set the permissions right. Put mysql and elastic users in the same group and then give access to that user on /tank

Comment: SOLUTION: chmod 755 /tank  Please put your anwser so I can accept it, you can put this chmod also. thank you

Comment: Glad i cud help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting this as an answer.

It was a file permissions issue. U need to ensure that the `mysql` user has access to the mysql datadir **and** the directory it is in, all the way to the root level directory.

If multiple users need access to these directories, then put them in a group and then give that group access to those directories.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just put the ZFS dataset in the location MySQL expects?

```
zfs set mountpoint=/var/lib/mysql tank/mysql
```

Now you don't have to worry about strange permissions on `/tank` and everything looks normal to the rest of the system.